# Where exactly is the isa pointer implemented in objects?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I read that the `isa` pointer looks for the instance method in a message to check if there really is that method in classes and their superclasses. So my question is, where is it implemented in objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you should not access the `isa` pointer directly to get an objects class but use `objc_getClass()` instead. In ARM64, for example, the `isa` field contains other flags (most notably the object's reference count if it is sufficiently small) in addition to the class pointer. See [this post by Mike Ash](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2013-09-27-arm64-and-you.html) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the runtime for a class you'll come across this...

```
typedef struct objc_class *Class;
typedef struct objc_object {
    Class isa;
} *id;
```

Edit:

Also in `NSObject.h`

```
/***********    Base class      ***********/

NS_ROOT_CLASS
@interface NSObject <NSObject> {
    Class   isa;
}
```